# Rust - Why we don't need borrow A when calling A::func(&self) from A self

Tags: rust

See the code:

```
struct A {}

impl A {
    fn a(&self) {}
}

pub fn main() {
    let a = A {};
    a.a();
    A::a(&a);
}
```

Why `a.a()` doesn't need the `&` while `A::a(&a)` needs? What's the difference?

Comment: The [dot operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/dot-operator.html) is literally syntax sugar for `A::a(&a)`.

Comment: @isaactfa, looks like an answer to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are Rust's exact auto-dereferencing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rust, `a.a()` is syntax sugar for `A::a(&a)`, so `a` does get borrowed in both calls. The dot operator does a lot more as well, you can read about that [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/dot-operator.html).

Comment: Also worth mentioning that, in the more general case, if `fn a(&self)` had a receiver of `&mut self` / `self`, the syntactic sugar would be `A::a(&mut a)` / `A::a(a)`, respectively